# Effect Size and ANOVA

Tags: anova, multilevel-analysis, effect-size

I have run a one-way ANOVA to check whether the mean score obtained by three groups of students from different schools is statistically significant ($n= 2000, 1500, 400$ respectively)and (unsurprisingly) found that the variance was statistically significant.  I calculated ETA squared which resulted in a 0.129 ES.

Assuming I've done everything right,

1. Is it legitimate to conclude that 13% of variance is attributable to type of school?
2. How can I find out which of the three schools is contributing most to the variance?

Comment: In the absence of more information, it sounds as though your concerns are common to the educational hierarchical model literature, i.e., there are hierarchical relationships between students and schools. ANOVA doesn't explicitly control for such relationships. Judith Singer's short paper *Using SAS PROC MIXED to Fit Multilevel Models* (https://www.ida.liu.se/~732G34/info/singer.pdf) is an excellent intro to this class of models in the educational lit. Forget the *SAS* part, it's simply generally informative.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

In the absence of more information, it sounds as though your concerns are common to the educational hierarchical model literature, i.e., there are hierarchical relationships between students and schools. ANOVA doesn't explicitly control for such relationships. Judith Singer's short paper [*Using SAS PROC MIXED to Fit Multilevel Models*](https://www.ida.liu.se/~732G34/info/singer.pdf) is an excellent intro to this class of models in the educational lit. Forget the SAS part, it's simply generally informative. – DJohnson

You could also look through some similar posts here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multilevel+educ*+answers%3A1